# Browser gives "No data received" when php code is loading a large database

Tags: php, browser, timeout

I am trying to load a large MySQL database using php (When it works, it takes about 1hr and 5 minutes to load).  Unfortunately, the browser times out with a "No data received" error when around 600,000 transactions out of 3+ million have been loaded into my MySQL database.  Chrome and Firefox both have this problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to display every single row at once? You would probably be better of lazy loading and showing them in batches.

Comment: Why are you doing an hour long operation as a web response? If it's a one-off hack then there are work-arounds for browser time-outs, but if it's for a real site no-one else is going to wait an hour for a page to load.

Comment: Thisis not a problem with the browsers. Your script is exceeding its time limit on the server. You can't run PHP scripts for that length of time as a web page. Either do it as a command line job, or find a way to execute it in background and check on its progress from time to time.